# Learning material on MSO-formulae

Tags: logic, reference-request

Does anyone know some website/book/etc. that provides learning material on writing MSO-formulae?

If there are solutions to it and/or if it is about language definability and rather concrete, that would be even better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MSO = Monadic Second order logic? I'm not sure what you mean precisely by "writing MSO formulae"... if you add some details and examples on what exactly you want, you probably have a better chance of getting a useful answer.

Comment: I learned from Automata Theory and its Applications by Khoussainov and Nerode. It focuses on concrete equivalences with automata.

Comment: @TomKern Thank you

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yes, I mean monadic second order logic. I am looking for something like "give an MSO formula that states that for a given graph there is a path from s to t"

Comment: Khoussainov & Nerode only talks about successor logics, since those are the ones that correspond to finite automata (the question of finding a notion of automaton that corresponds to a monadic second order graph logic is still open, to my knowledge). Downey & Fellows' Parameterized Complexity has a section on Courcelle's Theorem and MSO on graphs, but I don't think this is a good place to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MSO for graph structures, I recommend Section 3 of the following survey. It is very much readable compared to the canonical sources.

*Langer, Alexander; Reidl, Felix; Rossmanith, Peter; Sikdar, Somnath*, [**Practical algorithms for MSO model-checking on tree-decomposable graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cosrev.2014.08.001), Comput. Sci. Rev. 13-14, 39-74 (2014). [ZBL1302.68184](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1302.68184).